# Svmpredict returns usage and parameter definition

Tags: matlab, svm

this is my code

```
model=svmtrain(Label_Tr,Tr,'-c 1 -g 0.07 -b 1 -t 2');
[out_label,imacc] = svmpredict(L_Ts, Ts, model, '-b 1');
```

the svmtrain function performs iterations and gives results while the svmpredict repeatedly gives only usage definitions and parameter definitions

> Usage: [predicted_label, accuracy, decision_values/prob_estimates] = svmpredict(testing_label_vector, testing_instance_matrix, model, 'libsvm_options')
>          [predicted_label] = svmpredict(testing_label_vector, testing_instance_matrix, model, 'libsvm_options')

help needed here

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MATLAB`'s standard functions (currently `2015a`), There not a function called `svmpredict` anymore. Instead you can use `predict` function.

see the following example from MATHWORKS website:

```
load ionosphere
CVSVMModel = fitcsvm(X,Y,'Holdout',0.15,'ClassNames',{'b','g'},'Standardize',true);
CompactSVMModel = CVSVMModel.Trained{1};
testInds = test(CVSVMModel.Partition);  
XTest = X(testInds,:);
YTest = Y(testInds,:);
[label,score] = predict(CompactSVMModel,XTest);
```

check the help page for `[predict][1]` function.